# Call great grand children component method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I got a set of nested components as follows in Vue 2.2.1:

```
<Root>
  <VForm>
    <Accordion>
      <Panel>
        <Stripe ref="stripe">
```

And I need to call a method `getToken` on the Stripe component when the form is submitted. On my `<VForm>` component I have the following template.

```
<template>
  <form :method="method" :action="action" :class="classes" :autocomplete="autocomplete" @submit.prevent="submit">
    <slot></slot>
  </form>
</template>

<script>

  export default {

    props: {
      method: {
        type: String,
        default: 'POST'
      },
      action: {
        required: true,
        type: String
      },
      classes: {
        type: String
      },
      autocomplete: {
        type: String,
        default: 'on'
      }
    },

    methods: {
      submit(){
        this.$refs.stripe.getToken
      }
    }
  }

</script>
```

But I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getToken' of undefined`. I also tried it by emitting an event at the `<v-form>` level but, if i'm not mistaken, it is my understanding that the events flow from child to parent, so that didn't work.

How can I trigger `stripe.getToken` on `<v-form>` submit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a bus.

```
const bus = new Vue();

Vue.component("parent", {
    methods:{
        triggerStripe(){
            bus.$emit('get-token');
        }
    }
})

Vue.component("stripe",{
    mounted(){
        bus.$on('get-token', () => this.getToken());
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you, this works but I had to define the bus on the window object `window.bus = new Vue();` to make it globally accessible otherwise the stripe component would not receive the bus instance.

Comment: @enriqg9 True, when using single file components you would do that :)